# Is there a way to hook a function to make evaluation of its parameters lazy

Tags: python, python-decorators

See the following code example, is there any way to hook function "f"(may do it with some decorator), so that when flag is false, evaluation of the parameter "a" will not happen (function "f1" not called)

```
def f(flag, a):
    if flag:
        print(a)
    else:
        return
def f1():
    print('f1')
    return 'f1'

f(true,  f1()) #print f1 twice

f(false, f1()) #not print f1
```

Comment: `f1()` will be called well before `f()` is called and it's return value will be passed to `f()`, so even if `f()` doesn't evaluate `a`, `f1()` will execute

Comment: @AmalK my requirement from real project is that f is the logging function and f1 may be a heavy function. I want to have a flag to control not calling f1 when logging level is high.

Answer (score 3):

Arguments are always evaluated before calling the function.

The solution is to pass a reference to the function, and call it inside the other function.

```
def f(flag, a):
    if flag:
        print(a())

f(true, f1)
f(false, f1)
```